# how to efficiently retrieve the original string from a suffix tree?

Tags: string, algorithm, suffix-tree

If we have  the suffix tree of a string and also that suffix tree is not  an ukkonen's suffix tree i.e., we are given with a  normal suffix tree where edge labels are strings. How to efficiently get back original string from that suffix tree?

Answer (score 1):

The original string is the longest suffix, so you can just do a depth-first search to find the node for the longest string in the tree.